# Spring form option default selected

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, tags

I am facing  problem in getting a default value selected in the dropdown.
Code in my jsp is as below

```
<form:select path="codes" multiple="false">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select Code ---" />
    <form:options items="${statusQueryForm.codes}" />
</form:select>
```

Below is the code in statusQueryForm:

```
public void setCodes(Collection<String> codes) {
    this.codes = codes ;
}
public Collection<String> getCodes() {
    return codes;
}
```

Codes contains array list of Strings contains data like {"123","345"}

Now when the page is getting loaded,last option is selected 345.What I want is "Select code" should be selected by default.

Please someone can guide me in right direction.  I tried to understand the documentation but have failed to arrive at some sense in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to fix this by adding one more property code to the StatusQueryForm.   Jsp code was changed as below:.path was changed from codes to code

```
<form:select path="code" multiple="false">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select Code ---" />
    <form:options items="${statusQueryForm.codes}" />
</form:select>
```